# How can I draw curves from a CSV file in Gnuplot?

Tags: csv, graph, gnuplot

I have a CSV file like this and some rows like this:

```
E1  E1s E2  E2i i   p   s

47  3   25  0   20  0   47
```

I want to draw curves with respect to each column, but I get an error

> Bad data on line 1 of file final.csv

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may need a gnuplot tutorial. Try to learn how to use it before you post questions. This is not a tutorial site.

To get you started, comment out the first line with the '#' character. Assuming each column is its own line, plot these like this:

```
plot 'final.cvs' using 1 title 'E1'
replot 'final.cvs' using 2 title 'E1s'
```

Keep going like that for each column. The number after the 'using' command is the column number.